# entity framework - how to use generic add function with comparing navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

i'm a beginner with entity framework and also with generics.

***Question 1:***

I've following generic function for adding or using existing entities to db:

```
 public static T AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class
    {
        T modul;

            if (dbSet.Any())
            {
                modul = dbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
                if (modul == null)
                {
                    modul = dbSet.Add(entity);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                modul = dbSet.Add(entity);
            }
        return modul;
    }
```

I have a code first table with a navigation property to table properties:

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual ResourceType ResourceType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<Scan> ScanList { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ResourceObject> ParentResources { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
```

Now I want to change the generic method to comparing also the nullable properties of the entity and I'm not really sure how to master it. I think I need the right predicate?

***Question 2:***

I also got this function from stackoverflow:

```
public static void AddRangeIfNotExists<TEnt, TKey>(this DbSet<TEnt> dbSet, IEnumerable<TEnt> entities, Func<TEnt, TKey> predicate) where TEnt : class
    {
        var entitiesExist = from ent in dbSet
                            where entities.Any(add => predicate(ent).Equals(predicate(add)))
                            select ent;

        dbSet.AddRange(entities.Except(entitiesExist));
    }
```

Can someone please tellme how to use it for the question above, because i'm working with collections at the moment, maybe add range working faster?

ty

Answer (score 0):

If you have entities with same attributes, why not create a class called EntityBase, and make all of your entities extends it. And then, in your generic method change from 'where T : class' to 'where T : EntityBase'. Inside your method, you can have access to that attributes, example:

```
 public static T AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : EntityBase
    {
        if(entity.AttributeNullable == null)
        {
            //do some logic
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I use this function for a lot of other entities, so I can't modify it in that way. So I wrote an own function, not generic as a workaround. Maybe you can help me for an example call of the range function?